# Modeling has_one "active" child among has_many children

Tags: ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a model:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :progressions
  has_one :active_progression, class_name: "Progression"
end
```

And the child:

```
class Progression < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
end
```

I know that convention says I should create a separate foreign key inside `Progression` to associate the active progression with the Group's id (as that is how `has_one` works).

However, IMHO, it makes more logical sense to store the 'active' child's id in the Group model.

Edit: The reasoning is that storing the Group id in the Progression model as `active_group_id` or something similar is semantically confusing and opens the possibility of having multiple active progressions associated with a Group, which is obviously incorrect.

Edit 2: Additionally, a Progression should be able to be the active progression for multiple Groups. Creating an additional join-table seems redundant if only I was able to have the 'active' child's id stored in the Group model.

I have read several posts where people confuse the underlying `has_one` meaning, assuming it does the same thing as `belongs_to` but for the parent. I know this is not the case. `has_one` does the opposite of `belongs_to`, i.e. looking for the key in the counterpart instead of the calling model.

If Rails does not provide a method for creating an association of this nature, what is the most Railsy solution?

Comment: If you will add `active` property to `Progression` model, you can then add custom validation to `Progression` to ensure that there is only one `active` progression for it's group at any time (so if you will try to add another active progression, it will break). Then you can add method to `Group` (instead of `has_one`) that returns that active progression (with that `active` property set to true).

Comment: @KrzysztofWitczak then a progression would only be able to be 'active' for a single Group which means if all my groups happen to want the same progression as their active, there would be `Group.all * Progression` of identical progressions in the database. This cannot be the best way...

Comment: I see. Maybe, in that case, has_one :through https://dev.mikamai.com/2015/03/18/fun-with-rails-hasone-through-association/ could be helpful?

Comment: @KrzysztofWitczak thanks for the link! this is a great solution. i was hoping to avoid the use of another join table, but this will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

One option might be a method, on `Group`, such as:

```
def active_progression
  progressions.all.find { |p| p.id == active_progress_id }
end
```

The advantage of using a method is if you usually loop over all progressions anyway you only make one SQL call. The method looks up the active progression from the existing set of records.

Note that this is using the Ruby `#find` method (https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) not the ActiveRecord `#find` method.

Comment: why not put it all on SQL and actually use `ActiveRecord::find` e.g. `def active_progression; progressions.find(active_progess_id);end`? This avoids loading all `Progression`s into memory and iterating them to find just 1

Comment: That is a good option too, I suggested this because if you need all progressions and the active progress then it _should_ be one SQL call, not two. It really depends on the use case, e.g. if you just want to highlight the active row in a list of all progression just knowing the active_progress_id is enough.